# How to create a Primary Key in a dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic, primary-key

I don't know how to create a dynamic std::vector in which I want to allocate Usernames as PrimaryKeys, and each username would be a pointer to another dynamic vector containing structs that have the following information:

```
struct message{
    int id;
    char *msg;
    const string time;
};
```

I attach an illustrative image in order to make it more clear:
[image: Primary Key]

Where the username vector is the Primary Key pointing to a vector of structs previously mentioned.

How could I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a vector of usernames I preferred to use map this will guarantee that the username remains unique.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct message{
    int id;
    char *msg;
    const std::string time;
};


    int main()
    {
        std::map<std::string,std::vector<message *> > data;
        message message1,message2;
        message1.id  = 1;
        message1.msg = "Hi";

        message2.id  = 2;
        message2.msg = "Hello";
        std::vector<message *> messages;
        messages.push_back(&message1);
        messages.push_back(&message2);
        data["smith"] = messages;
        std::cout << (data["smith"]).at(0)->msg << std::endl;

    }
```